# Why my reverse() method doesn't work in python 3?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, list, reverse

I was trying to do this exercise where you have to take a word and check if it's a palindrome. I tried to do it with making a string in to a list then reversing it and turning it back to a string, but the reverse method doesn't work for me for some reason, I checked and the usage is correct.

```
word = input('Give me a word:\n')
b = []
wordLetters = word.split()
b = wordLetters.reverse()
word2 = ''.join(b)

if word == word2:
    print('Yay')
else:
    print('heck')
```

it just shows

> TypeError: can only join an iterable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python `reverse` method of `list` does the operation in-place e.g. it modifies the list you apply this operation to. This method has no return value.

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4]
l.reverse()
print(l)
```

Output:

```
[4, 3, 2, 1]
```

If you try to get value returned by `reverse` you will get `None`:

```
print([1, 2, 3, 4].reverse())
```

Output:

```
None
```

If you need a reversed copy of your list you should use `reversed` function:

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4]
r = reversed(l)
print(r)
print(list(r))
```

Output:

```
<list_reverseiterator object at 0x7ff37e288ef0>
[4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Notice that it returns iterator, not the list itself. You can pass that iterator to `join` function or you can build a list from it using `list` constructor.

The same is true for method `sort` and function `sorted`.

Answer (score 0):

reverse() method of list doesn't return anything but reverses  the list itself in Python 3. So join wordLetters not b.Hope this solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

As the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) states:

> list.reverse()
>
> Reverse the elements of the list in place.

That means this method won't return anything (otherwise it would state what it returns) and that it reverses the list in-place.

Also `str.split` will (by default) split at whitespaces which is probably not intended from the problem description.

My suggestion would be to simply use slice notation for reversing the string:

```
word = input('Enter your word')
if word == word[::-1]:
    print('Yay')
else:
    print('heck')
```