# Reverse list method print None for a list returned in a function?

Tags: python, list, function, reverse

I have this code, the code print the List, the List with the first and last number swapped and the reverse of this list but I am having problem for printing the list because I need to use `.reverse()` method, I already solved with `swapped[::-1]` but I need to do it with reverse list method. This is my code:

```
import random
def swap(myList):
    myList[0],myList[-1]=myList[-1],myList[0]
    return myList

myList = []
for i in range(5):
    myList.append(random.randint(1,10))
print('List:',myList)
swapped=swap(myList)
a=swapped
print('New List: ',swapped)
print('Reversing:', swapped.reverse())
```

This is my output:

```
Old List: [7, 6, 10, 5, 6]
New List: [7, 5, 10, 6, 6]
Reversing: None
```

A Tried this from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48241461/9550633) an it works but what about `x.reverse()`:

```
print('Reversing1:',list(reversed(swapped)))
```

This is the results for you check the true answer:

```
Old List: [1, 8, 8, 6, 1]
New List: [1, 8, 8, 6, 1]
Reversing1: [1, 6, 8, 8, 1]
```

but I want to do it with .reverse() function what's the problem with the method `x.reverse()`?

Comment: Just as it says in the documentation, the `list.reverse()` method returns nothing.  Its effect is entirely the modification it performs to the list you invoke it on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`list.reverse()` mutates the list in-place and returns `None`. `reverse` leaves the original list alone and returns a reversed version of it.